# How to write query in documentdb to match exact arrays?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Suppose in documentdb collection I have 1 document:

i.e. `{
  "school": "1254",
  "types": [
    "manager","customer", "teacher","principal"
  ]
}`

Now I want to write 1 query with types, suppose I have types with same values of existing document then how can I match both array in query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you construct (in code) a query with a bunch of `AND`s like this, if you want a subset match:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE <myArray[0]> IN c.types AND <myArray[1]> IN c.types...
```

Or like this if you want a truly exact match including order:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.types[0] = <myArray[0]> AND c.types[1] = <myArray[1]>...
```

Or like this if you want exact but not with order:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.types[0] IN <myArray> AND c.types[1] IN <myArray>...
```

My guess is that they would all perform about the same but if you found that the two with `IN` clauses did not perform as well as the one using `=`, then you might want to sort the arrays when you store them and sort the one you go to compare to.

You could also use a UDF to accomplish this but that would not allow for the use of an index and result in a full table scan. That said, if you have other highly selective criteria, then using a UDF at that end of your `WHERE` clause might be OK.

Comment: larry thanks for your reply, but I could not resolve my issue with query, may be I need to write UDF to fulfill my requirement.